# Environment variables of current process

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I'm trying to find the environment variables of a currently running process.

Let the executable be `test`. What I'm doing:

```
./test // first run test
```

Inside the program I have a print statement doing `getpid()` which prints out the current process's pid when the executable starts executing.

Then using the pid printed out to the console, I do,

```
strings /proc/<pid>/environ
```

Now, is there any other way to specify the pid without explicitly writing it out first?

I saw in one of the videos that they specify the pid with a command like this:

```
seed@ubuntu:~/test$ strings /proc/$$/environ | grep LOGNAME
LOGNAME=seed
```

I didn't understand it quite correctly. Assuming `test` as the executable, I tried:

```
seed@ubuntu: ./test$ strings /proc/\$\$/environ | grep LOGNAME
```

But it returns:

```
bash: /test$: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

OS: Seed Ubuntu 16.04 (32 bit) running on Virtual Box 
GCC Version: 5.4.0

[**Link to video**](https://youtu.be/tZblgb5LYmk?t=955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminal session transcript,

```
seed@ubuntu:~/test$ strings /proc/$$/environ | grep LOGNAME
```

the `seed@ubuntu:~/test$` part is just the user's prompt string - the actual command is

```
strings /proc/$$/environ | grep LOGNAME
```

Here, `$$` (**without** backslashes) is the PID of the shell, as described in the `Special parameters` section of `man bash`:

> ```
>  $      Expands  to  the  process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it
>           expands to the process ID of the current  shell,  not  the  sub‐
>           shell.
> ```

So this command returns the value of `LOGNAME` in the shell's environment - it's not really meant for examining the environment of a process invoked *from* the shell (although in general, the process will inherit the shell's environment).

---

Inside a C program, you can obtain the values of environment variables much more directly, using the `getenv` function:

> ```
> GETENV(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 GETENV(3)
>
> NAME
>        getenv, secure_getenv - get an environment variable
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include <stdlib.h>
>
>        char *getenv(const char *name);
> ```

So for example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char *envval;

  if((envval = getenv("LOGNAME")) != NULL) {
    printf("Value of LOGNAME is: %s\n", envval);
  }
  else {
    printf("LOGNAME not found in environment\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

such that

```
$ gcc -o getenv_test getenv_test.c

$ LOGNAME=foo ./getenv_test 
Value of LOGNAME is: foo
```